# try-catch block not suppressing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am getting the java.lang.NullPointerException and i am not sure why. I am trying to use a try-catch block but it does not work. Can anyone explain what is wrong with this block?

```
public PriceDataAdder(Connection conn) {
        try {
            this.conn = conn;
            statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `blah` (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,`i`,j) VALUE( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PriceDataAdder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to know a) why you are getting a NPE or b) why it's not being caught? a) Not possible to say with the information you've given but conn may be null b) you're catching a SQLException not a NPE

Comment: Probably the `conn` getting passed in is null; _there's_ your problem.

Comment: Do NOT try to catch a NullPointerException. Fix your code instead. To figure out why an exception is thrown, use a debugger. In modern IDEs, you can also add Java Exception Breakpoints to your debugger if you'd only like to stop running your code and check what is happening when the given exception is thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try catching `Exception` instead of `SQLException`. It will work because `Exception` is the superclass of all exceptions, and by catching it you're catching all possible exceptions that might get generated inside the `try` block.

Anyway, the problem is probably caused because `conn` is `null` at the point where `prepareStatement()` is called, start by making sure that you're passing a correct instance of `Connection` where the `PriceDataAdder` method is called.

Also take a look at the log that's being generated, that `Logger` object should be put to good use.

Comment: I don't think it's preferable to catch `NullPointerException`s in this case, but that's indeed why it's not caught.

Answer (score 4):

You are only catching `SQLException` objects, and `NullPointerException` is not a subclass of `SQLException`. You can insert `NullPointerException|` to catch those also; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html.

Comment: Note that multi-catch parameters are only allowed in Java 7+.

Comment: Please don't do this. NEVER catch NullPointerException. Fix your code first.

Answer (score 2):

You should manage your exception like the below code

```
try {
    this.conn = conn;
    statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `blah` (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,`i`,j) VALUE( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PriceDataAdder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PriceDataAdder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PriceDataAdder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Don't catch NullPointerException, but prevent it in the first place by ensuring 'conn' is not null.

Comment: @mhaller Thats true, but still we have to catch that exception also.

Comment: Nonsense, you do not have to catch NullPointerException. In fact, you should really not catch it in this case, since it is a programming mistake to use 'conn' although it's null. Catchine NPE here is just hiding the real bug.

Comment: @mhaller Yes you are right, still we have to catch if not then programm execution will be stopped.

Comment: Bhavik, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586290/is-catching-a-null-pointer-exception-a-code-smell and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716353/if-catching-null-pointer-exception-is-not-a-good-practice-is-catching-exception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778439/is-it-bad-style-to-use-nullpointerexception-to-test-for-null